# How to add item to product backlog in TFS if you've closed the Add Box

Tags: tfs

Ok, you can laugh now, but seriously, I can't find how to get the 'add item' box back.

Yes, the box here, then you click Add:
[image]

I closed it, and can't get it back, any ideas? I dare you to close yours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the top right of your photo, underneath the velocity graph, there is a label that says **add items**. Click that, and the box should come back up.

Comment: Also, this totally happened to me, too.

Comment: Hero! Seriously though, there's a lot to be said about having links that actually LOOK like links! Thanks. (Glad I'm not the only one)

Comment: I was slightly embarrassed with myself that I had to search for this. Pleased it's not just me.